# jquery ajax parse response text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Ok this is really frusturating me because I've done this a hundred times before, and this time it isn't working.  So I know I'm doing something wrong, I just can't figure it out.

I am using the jQuery .get routine to load html from another file.  I don't want to use .load() because it always replaces the children of the element I'm loading content into.

Here is my .get request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.get('info.html', {}, function(html) {
        // debug code
        console.log($(html).find('ul').html());
        // end debug code
    });
});
```

The file 'info.html' is a standard xhtml file with a proper doctype, and the only thing in the body is a series of ul's that I need to access.  For some reason, the find function is giving me a null value.

In firebug, the GET request is showing the proper RESPONSE text and when I run

```
console.log(html);
```

Instead of the current console.log line, I get the whole info.html as output, like I would expect.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot pull in an entire XHTML document. You can only handle tags that exist within the `<body>` of an html document. Frustrating. Strip everything from info.html that isn't within your `<body>` tag and try it again.

There are other potential ways around this issue - check below "Stackoverflow Related Items" at the base of this response.

> From the Doc: (http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#htmlownerDocument)
>
> *"HTML string cannot contain elements that are invalid within a div, such as
> html, head, body, or title elements.*"

#### Stackoverflow Related Items:

- [Simple jQuery ajax example not finding elements in returned HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1033460/simple-jquery-ajax-example-not-finding-elements-in-returned-html)
- [What is the best practice for parsing remote content with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034881/what-is-the-best-practice-for-parsing-remote-content-with-jquery)

Comment: So I need to write a php script to sit inbetween the 2 html files and have the get request go there, huh....that is frusturating, i was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: I believe so, yes. In all honesty, you could use phpQuery within your PHP Script. it will allow you jQuery style selectors making it easy to return the <BODY> contents.

Comment: stripping out everything but what's within the <body> doesn't work either...i get the correct response but can't parse it...thanks anyway!

Comment: Your document is well-formed, right? Nothing like <span/> etc in it?

Comment: no, it's just html->body->ul->li.  body has a few ul->li sets under it but it's all valid.  I decided i am just going to use .load() into a hidden div, parse the data, and prepend the parsed data to where i want it to be

Comment: Before you do that, check out my answer - I've found a couple resources for you that might help.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. But, if you have more than one UL in the returned html then ".find('ul').html()" is only going to give you the html for the first of those elements.

Comment: Triffid, are you sure about that? I was thinking it might return all of the LI's from any of the UL elements.

Answer (score 8):

I know this is an old post but I've been having the EXACT same frustrating problem for a couple of hours and have found a solution. For me what actually worked was to have the html content wrapped with a **form** tag.

So having the following html source:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <body>
   <form>
    <div id="content">Some Stuff</div>
   </form>
  </body>
 </head>
</html>
```

With this jquery snippet should work:

```
var callback = function (data) {
   alert($("#content", $(data)).html());
};
$.get(url, null, callback, null);
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Well, your syntax helped a lot. `alert($("#content", $(data)))` <- didn't know about this. You can just do `$.get(url, callback);
`, but I guess you were explicit for a reason. PS: as you can see, you're missing a ')'.

Comment: I just corrected the missing ')' and a couple of spell checks, thank you so much @nush.

Comment: Your code says: `alert($()).html();` Should be: `alert($().html());`

Answer (score 6):

I have found this being pretty clean solution:

```
var elementInResponse = $("<div>").html(responseText).find(selector);
```

Comment: This leaves out the head and body tag for me

Answer (score 3):

Wanting to do the same thing and knowing that JQuery load(..) does it, I had a look in the code.  While you can't turn a complete html response directly into a JQuery object, you can append it to one so:

```
function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
    $(target).html(jQuery("<div>").append(data).find("#snippet"));
    // Create a dummy div to hold the results,
    // inject the contents of the document into it,
    // Locate the specified elements
}
```

The response from the server that goes into data is like:

```
<! doctype ... >
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="snippet">
      <p>Some content here that we are interested in</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is a very important answer. Contrary to answers in nearly every other thread on this subject, neither `$(data)` nor `$.parseHTML(data)` will return a jQuery object such that you can chain on methods like `.find()` etc. Appending it to an open div tag is the only thing that works for me in jQuery 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try including whole body within a `<div>` tag, e.g. `<body><div>content</div></body>`.