# Query HTML returned from AJAX

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

How can I query HTML thats returned from AJAX?

I tried

```
$.post("gethtml.php", { url: $url.val() }, function(data) {
    var $html = $(data),
            $links = $("link, script, style", $html),
            $body = $("body", $html);

    $links.each(function() { $(this).addClass("tmp"); });
    console.log($html);
    console.log($body.html());
});
```

`$html` looks like `[meta, title, script, style#gstyle, script, textarea#csi, div#mngb, iframe, center, script, script]` and `$body.html()` null

**UPDATE**

A simple setup at http://jsfiddle.net/uvnrJ/1/

```
$(function() {
  var html = "<!doctype html><html><head><title>title here ... </title></head><body>This is the body</body></html>",
      $html = $(html);
  console.log($html); // jQuery(title, <TextNode textContent="This is the body">)
  console.log($html.find("body")); // jQuery()
  console.log($html.find("title")); // jQuery()
  console.log($html.filter("title")); // jQuery(title)
});
```

Shows that jQuery seem to have problems parsing the HTML string?

Comment: Have you tried `$body = $(data).find('body');`?

Comment: @experimentX I am trying to get the HTML source of another web page.

Comment: are you getting results? i guess you might be having problem at parsing it, try something like Sly suggests.

Comment: @experimentX, I think u are right. jQuery seems to have problems parsing a simple HTML string? see update

Answer (score 3):

Try this...

```
..........
var elements = $('<div></div>');
elements.html(data);
alert(elements.find('body').html());
...........
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should search for your elements directly in the `data` variable or use the `find()` method on `$(data)`. Something like:

```
$.post("gethtml.php", { url: $url.val() }, function(data) {
    var $html = $(data).find('html'), // First way
        $links = $("link, script, style", data), // Second way
        $body = $("body", data); // Could be better written as $(data).find('body')

    $links.each(function() { $(this).addClass("tmp"); });
    console.log($html);
    console.log($body.html());
});
```

Comment: That dont appear to work, u can try a very simple setup http://jsfiddle.net/uvnrJ/1/ as you can see, jQuery seem to detect only the title tag + a text node somehow. I think thats the cause of the problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jiewmeng Yeah its seems like it's not possible using jQuery. Have a look at this answer [jquery ajax parse response text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1050333/jquery-ajax-parse-response-text) and in particular this one [What is the best practice for parsing remote content with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034881/what-is-the-best-practice-for-parsing-remote-content-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and was forced to resort to parsing the HTML string directly:

```
    var headStartIndex = htmlString.toLowerCase().indexOf("<head>") + "<head>".length;
    var headEndIndex = htmlString.toLowerCase().indexOf("</head>");
    var newHead = htmlString.substring(headStartIndex, headEndIndex);

    var bodyStartIndex = htmlString.toLowerCase().indexOf("<body>") + "<body>".length;
    var bodyEndIndex = htmlString.toLowerCase().indexOf("</body>");
    var newBody = htmlString.substring(bodyStartIndex, bodyEndIndex);

    console.log(newHead);
    console.log(newBody);
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this, This works

```
$.ajax({
    'url': url,
    'dataType': 'html',
    'success': function(e){
        var $div = $("<div id='_some_id'>" + e + "</div>");
        $div = $div.filter("_some_id");
        $div.find("span"); // you can search for anything here. it would work now
    }
});
```